# How to handle big numbers that are represented by big-integer in angular primeng chart?

Tags: angular, primeng, biginteger

I am having a situation where I have to display numbers that are at least 35 places in length. I am using primeng line chart and this value has to be represented in Y axis of the chart. At present i am getting it displayed as exponential values, but i want the actual numbers to be displayed. I have tried to bind the values as string, but that did not work out too.